# JQuery Adding link to a table cell

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add an a tag to a table cell.  My code is working all the way up to the final line shown here, at which point I get an exception of

'TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method'

From what I've read, appendChild should be a method on my table cell.

```
    var rowId = "#rowid-" + response.id;
    var actionCell = $('#itemlist').find(rowId).find(actionCellId);
    //Add my Edit link                
    link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', '/MYSite/Item/Edit?itemID=' + response.id);
    link.setAttribute('id', 'edit-' + response.id);
    var linkText = document.createTextNode('Edit');
    link.appendChild(linkText);
    //Exception occurs on this line
    actionCell.appendChild(link);
```

Comment: Why arent you just using the jQuery append?

Comment: I'll have to look that up. I'm pretty new to JQuery and not the most experienced javascript developer either.

Comment: `actionCell` is a jQuery object. It doesn't have the `appendChild()` method. I agree with @MechSoftware: it's better not to mix and match jQuery and pure JavaScript methods.

Comment: I found what I needed to do by googling javascript as I couldn't find it googling jquery. That's the reason for the mix.  Once @Mech Software suggested jQuery append, I found the solution.  I didn't know where to search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace this:

```
link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', '/MYSite/Item/Edit?itemID=' + response.id);
link.setAttribute('id', 'edit-' + response.id);
var linkText = document.createTextNode('Edit');
link.appendChild(linkText);
//Exception occurs on this line
actionCell.appendChild(link);
```

With this:

```
$('<a>Edit</a>').attr({
    'href': '/MYSite/Item/Edit?itemID=' + response.id,
    'id': 'edit-' + response.id
}).appendTo(actionCell);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I tried doing something similar looking at the append method, but my solution didn't work.  Thanks a bunch.